# how to select top 20 rows - top10 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to display a table of mysql db,Each time (query) 10 lines are displayed, for example i have this table with id = `uuid()` :

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| id                                   | name   |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| 32dcad0b-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item0  |
| 32e07686-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item1  |
| 32e07772-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item2  |
| 32e077af-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item3  |
| 32e077f2-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item4  |
| 32e07825-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item5  |
| 32e078bf-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item6  |
| 32e07954-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item7  |
| 32e0798c-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item8  |
| 32e07a26-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item9  |
| 32e07a5a-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item10 |
| 32eacb03-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item11 |
| 32eacb83-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item12 |
| 32eacbb2-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item13 |
| 32eacbe0-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item14 |
| 32eacc0e-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item15 |
| 32eacc37-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item16 |
| 32eacca3-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item17 |
| 32eaccd1-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item18 |
| 32eaccff-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item19 |
| 32eacd2d-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item20 |
| 32eacd56-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item21 |
| 32eacd85-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item22 |
| 32eacdae-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item23 |
| 32eacdd7-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item24 |
| 32eace00-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item25 |
| 32eace29-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item26 |
| 32eace57-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item27 |
| 32eace80-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item28 |
| 32eacea9-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item29 |
| 32eaced2-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item30 |
| 32eacefb-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item31 |
| 32eacf24-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item32 |
| 32eacf52-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item33 |
| 32eacf7b-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item34 |
| 32eacfa5-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item35 |
| 32eacfce-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item36 |
| 32eacff7-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item37 |
| 32ead025-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item38 |
| 32ead04e-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item39 |
| 32ead07c-3cc3-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce | item40 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

how i can select top 10 item then top 20 item - top 10 item ... etc

Comment: Have a look at the [limit clause of the select statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Comment: If you want to select rows 11-20, use `LIMIT 10, 10` (meaning skip 10 rows, and get the next 10 rows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select rows in MySQL starting at a given row number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1252673/1255289)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **LIMIT** clause like below. The first argument is the offset and the second is the number of rows you want to display after the offset.

```
SELECT id from TABLE Limit 0,10
SELECT id from TABLE Limit 10,10
SELECT id from TABLE Limit 20,10
```

...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name 
FROM [table_name]
[ORDER BY name]
LIMIT [number_of_rows]
```